# Can't unshorten bit.ly urls?

Tags: python, url, header, http-headers

I'm using the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153096/how-can-i-un-shorten-a-url-using-python/7153185#7153185) stackoverflow post to unshorten urls...

```
import httplib
import urlparse

def unshorten_url(url):
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    h = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
    resource = parsed.path
    if parsed.query != "":
        resource += "?" + parsed.query
    h.request('HEAD', resource )
    response = h.getresponse()
    if response.status/100 == 3 and response.getheader('Location'):
        return unshorten_url(response.getheader('Location')) # changed to process chains of short urls
    else:
        return url
```

All shortened links get unshortned 'cept for newly created bit.ly urls.

I get this error:

```
>>> unshorten_url("bit.ly/1atTViN")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in unshorten_url
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 955, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 989, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 754, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

What gives?

Comment: downvote the originally posted answer which recieved 6 upvotes

Comment: @user2799617: then downvote the original, not this question.

Comment: http://www.ankitpanda.com/tweeting-with-python/, but i've tried with another url as well... youtube.com/watch?v=eeAjkbNq4xI

Comment: and oddly this older bit.ly url, http://bit.ly/GVBQJS, gets unshorten just not the newer ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to include the URL scheme:

```
unshorten_url("http://bit.ly/1atTViN")
```

Note the `http://` there, that is *important*. Without it, the URL is not parsed correctly:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urlparse('bit.ly/1atTViN')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='bit.ly/1atTViN', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.urlparse('http://bit.ly/1atTViN')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='bit.ly', path='/1atTViN', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

See how the `netloc` parameter is empty when no `http://` is included; you end up trying to connect to your own machine instead, and you are not running a webserver so the connection is refused.

Answer (score 0):

Probably bit.ly is refusing connections from tools like httplib. You can try to change user agent like this:

```
h.putheader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.7.10) Gecko/20050717 Firefox/1.0.6')
```

Comment: The connection is refused *before* headers are sent.