# Asynchronous URL un-shortening in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, discord.py, grequests

I am currently trying to implement a feature into my program that will detect and unshorten any URL shorteners, including bit.ly and old goo.gl links (now no longer existent). I have found a few articles, and I am going to discuss my current experiments, findings and ask the question of "Is there even a way to do it?"

I started off by reading up on any previously found articles. I found a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425378/how-to-un-shorten-resolve-a-url-using-python-when-final-url-is-https) on how to un-shorten URLs using Python. The answer pointed to the `requests` library, using `requests.head`, setting `allow_redirects` to `True`. `requests` does not function with async.io at all. Which is where I found a question based on Async requests with Python requests (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests))

This question pointed to `grequests`, which is an async version of requests, however, when I attempted the code from the first question, replacing `requests` with `grequests`, it did not show the link location after re-directs. I then changed the `.head` to `.get`, and while it did work, it still provided the bit.ly URL I was using, rather than the un-shortened URL.

I am unsure what I could use to find the URL location after unshortening without making it synchronous rather than async. If anyone can help, that would be really useful!

Comment: Which Python version are you running?

Comment: Currently running 3.7 @Tomalak

Comment: If your goal is to *"not block the main thread"* (as opposed to *"must be done with asyncio"*), you could use multithreading with the `requests` library.

Comment: I need to do it with asyncio, due to my other imports. It cannot be done with multithreading (or multiprocessing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good library that I would recommend using is [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/), a library which allows for asynchronous web requests.

Answer (score -3):

Try this and then run it as a loop on your data frame using .apply(lambda) :

```
import requests

def unshortenurlx(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        return(response.url)
    except Exception as e:
        return('Bad url {url}. {e}'.format(url=url, e=e))
```