# Unshorten url in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib3, http.client

I am using this code for unshortening urls in python 3 , but the code returns the url as it is (shortened), so what should I do to get it unshortened?

```
import requests
import http.client
import urllib.parse as urlparse   

def unshortenurl(url):
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url) 
    h = http.client.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc) 
    h.request('HEAD', parsed.path) 
    response = h.getresponse() 
    if response.status/100 == 3 and response.getheader('Location'):
        return response.getheader('Location') 
    else: return url
```

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153185/7965185

Comment: I am using this exact code, and it does not work

Comment: [`if 300 <= response.status < 400`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628825/1270789) would be much better and clearer here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3 `response.status/100 == 3` would be `True` only for status code 300. For any other 3xx code it would be `False`. Use floor division instead `response.status//100 == 3` or some other way to test for redirection codes.

EDIT: It looks you are using the code from [SO question posted by @Aybars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7153185/7965185) and there is comment at the top of the snippet what to do in python3. Also, it would have been nice to mention the source of the code.

Comment: Tried to change response.status/100 == 3 to response.status//100 == 3 but did not solve the problem

Comment: Check the comment at the top of the code from original SO question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, is there a way to check if the url is shortened or not, so that I unshorten only the shortened ones in order to gain time!