# Unshorten the URL without downloading whole page in python

Tags: python

I want to unshorten URLs to get the real address.In some cases there are more than one redirection. I have tried using urllib2 but it seems to be making GET requests which is consuming time and bandwidth. I want get only the headers so that I have the final URL without needing to get the whole body/data of that page.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute a HTTP HEAD request to get just the headers.

The second answer shows how to perform a HEAD request using urllib.
[How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)

Comment: @Pranay: Also see the `urllib2` answer in the above mentioned link.

Comment: I have tried that already as given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201062/how-can-i-unshorten-a-url-using-python but it doesn't work. example address "http://nyti.ms/pvUj8c" it gives back error like socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: @Rangrag : it seems your solution also downloads the whole page!

Comment: import httplib
import urlparse

def unshorten_url(url):
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    h = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
    h.request('HEAD', parsed.path)
    response = h.getresponse()
    if response.status/100 == 3 and response.getheader('Location'):
        return response.getheader('Location')
    else:
        return url

Comment: @Gregor : Sorry for the formatting but i just posted the code I am using and i am getting  this error                                          socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: Your code works for me.

unshorten_url("http://nyti.ms/pvUj8c")
'http://feeds.nytimes.com/click.phdo?i=a621defd69034ebb3e896cbe284a8ae4'

Comment: @Gregor : strange thing. Actually it working for some of the address like www.iitd.ac.in(my college) but not for the one i mentioned.But when I use urllib it works fine for all the shortened URL but takes time. BTW i am behind a proxy.should that matter ?

Comment: If your proxy does not allow/forward HEAD requests, this can't work.

Comment: @Gregor : oh, thanks.I guess that seems to be the issue.But is there any way to confirm that my proxy is the culprit(some command to check proxy behavior) or is there any way around to this without making GET requests ?