# Using python to expand a bit.ly link

Tags: python, html, url, hyperlink, bit.ly

How can I use Python to take a bit.ly link and return the fully expanded link?

If the link inputted is not a bit.ly link, the original link should be returned.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201062/how-can-i-unshorten-a-url-using-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.urlopen('http://bit.ly/1cPIdPg').url
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

You can also use the `geturl()` method:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> print urllib2.urlopen('http://bit.ly/1cPIdPg').geturl()
```

And, for Python 3:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> print(urlopen('http://bit.ly/1cPIdPg').geturl())
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) module

```
import urllib
response = urllib.urlopen('http://bit.ly/1mlEbqY')
print response.url
```

Outputs:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689592/using-python-to-expand-a-bit-ly-link
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `requests` library of Python. Below is the code

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http_tiny_url_for_stackoverflow_or_any')
print r.url
```

Output:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```