# Unshorten Flic.kr URLs

Tags: python, url, flickr, url-shortener

I have a Python script that unshortens URLs based on the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201062/how-can-i-unshorten-a-url-using-python). So far it worked pretty well, e.g., with `youtu.be`, `goo.gl`,`t.co`, `bit.ly`, and `tinyurl.com`. But now I noticed that it doesn't work for Flickr's own URL shortener flic.kr.

For example, when I enter the URL

```
https://flic.kr/p/qf3mGd
```

into a browser, I get redirected correctly to

```
https://www.flickr.com/photos/106783633@N02/15911453212/
```

However, when using to unshorten the same URL with the Python script I get the following re-directs

```
https://flic.kr/p/qf3mgd
http://www.flickr.com/photo.gne?short=qf3mgd
http://www.flickr.com/signin/?acf=%2Fphoto.gne%3Fshort%3Dqf3mgd
https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=flickrsignin&.pc=8190&.scrumb=[...]
```

thus eventually ending up on the Yahoo login page. [Unshort.me](http://unshort.me/), by the way, can unshorten the URL correctly. What am I missing here?

Here is the full source code of my script. I stumbled upon some pathological cases with the original script:

```
import urlparse
import httplib


def unshorten_url(url, max_tries=10):
    return __unshorten_url(url, [], max_tries)

def __unshorten_url(url, check_urls, max_tries):
    if max_tries == 0:
        if len(check_urls) > 0:
            return check_urls[0]
        return url
    if url in check_urls:
        return url
    unshortended = ''
    try:
        parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        h = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
        h.request('HEAD', url)
    except:
        return None
    try:
        response = h.getresponse()
    except:
        return url


    if response.status/100 == 3 and response.getheader('Location'):
        unshortended = response.getheader('Location')
    else:
        return url
    #print max_tries, unshortended
    if unshortended != url:
        if 'http' not in unshortended:
            return url
        check_urls.append(url)
        return __unshorten_url(unshortended, check_urls, (max_tries-1))
    else:
        return unshortended

print unshorten_url('http://t.co/5skmePb7gp')
```

EDIT: Full working example with a `t.co` URL

Comment: Umm... this isn't the full script, and the error is likely outside of here. Could you get rid of some of the non-crucial bits and post a more complete code sample?

Comment: Changed it to a working stand-alone script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Request [0] rather than httplib in this way and it's works fine with https://flic.kr/p/qf3mGd like urls:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.head("https://flic.kr/p/qf3mGd", allow_redirects=True, verify=False).url
u'https://www.flickr.com/photos/106783633@N02/15911453212/'
```

[0] http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: This works fine indeed and makes my methods basically obsolete :). Thanks a lot!