# Can I store a redirected url into a variable with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm working on a Discordbot that takes links to music posted in a channel and stores them in an array. I'm using it to create a queue of all the submitted tracks.

Most people link SoundCloud or YouTube links. Which is working fine so far.
But sometimes people post a link starting with https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl
Which redirects to the actual https://soundcloud.com/username/track

Same thing with https://youtu.be which redirects to https://youtube.com/etcetc

```
const client_2 = new Discord.Client();    
client_2.on('message', async (msg) => {
const linksubmit = "https://";
if (msg.content.startsWith(linksubmit)) {
let submit = msg.toString();
    }
}
```

This stores any posted link into the variable submit. But is there a way to find the redirect url, and then store it into the variable? (with JavaScript)

Comment: You can check the headers for a location header, You will have to fetch it first, if you can fetch the headers only this will be more light weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can think of is using the `replace()` method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced [[read more]](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp). so you can do script to rewrite your links were it changes to fit your format, like this:

```js
var URLRewriter = function(a, b) {
    $('a[href*="' + a + '"]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(a, b));
    });
};

URLRewriter('youtu.be', 'youtube.com');
```

Comment: Ah yeah that will definitely work for youtube.be links.  cause the youtu.be links already have the relevant data in the url for the redirect.
example: 
https://youtu.be/Hjci0x-ZnhY  redirects to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hjci0x-ZnhY but the soundcloud.app.goo.gl are a complete redirect.

example:
https://soundcloud.app.goo.gl/ZNGsRFCn5WsWUBj38 redirects to https://soundcloud.com/jason-pecina/sober/s-qnnQiqEqev3

Comment: @SilvesterRoseboom it seems like soundcloude is using the goo_gl api to do the shortening, i recommend to take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201062/how-can-i-unshorten-a-url and if my answer helped please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers